# Rx Scheduler and Thread affinity

Tags: multithreading, system.reactive

Can't understand, how scheduler works in Rx Framework. I run code, mention below and recived that "Select thread" and "Subscribe thread" produces same values, and main thread produces antoher value. I thought that "main thread" and "subscribe thread" must have the same value, and "select thread" must have another.

```
var obs = Observable.Range(1, 10)
    .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.ThreadPool)
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread);

var data = obs.Select(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Select thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    return x;
});

data.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("Subscribe thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));

Console.WriteLine("Main thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made the same mistake that I think everyone does when first looking at the schedulers - I certainly did.

The mistake is thinking that `Scheduler.CurrentThread` uses the thread that **defined** the observable - instead it is the thread that is **executing** the observable.

So the `Select` is only called when the observable is subscribed to and since you've subscribed to it on the `ThreadPool` it will also be observed on the same thread (`CurrentThread`).

Comment: And one more silly question. If i want to make calculations on the background thread, i.e. select operator and others, how to reach it? Or all calculations is always on the separate thread?

Comment: @INs - You can schedule on the dispatcher for WPF/Silverlight or using a `Control` in Windows Forms. Otherwise you can create an `EventLoopScheduler` instance to schedule to a specific thread, but you can't schedule to the current thread - it doesn't make sense to be able to do so as this would imply some magical message pump on an arbitrary thread.

Comment: @INs - Having said that, you can use the blocking operations, such as `First` to get values out of an observable on to the current thread.

Comment: CurrentThread works similarly to Immediate but does some things to make it less likely you'll deadlock yourself